# Laravel login with Socialize

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

i have problem with Socialize login, exactly when I accept application on facebook,i go to redirect, callback and i dont have user parametr.
So if I use `dd(Socialize::with("facebook")->user());`, i got error 500.
I set configuration in  service file.
Someone have any idea what is wrong?

My controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect;
use Socialize;


class FacebookController extends Controller {

    public function facebook() {
        return Socialize::with("facebook")->redirect();
    }

    public function callback(Request $request) {
         $code = $request->get('code');

        dd(Socialize::with("facebook")->user());
        $user = Socialize::with("facebook")->user();    
        return $user;
    }

}
```

My services:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env("FB_APP_ID"),
    'client_secret' => env("FB_APP_SECRET"),
    'redirect' => env("REDIRECT_URL"),
],
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/facebook','FacebookController@facebook');                Route::get('/callback','FacebookController@callback');
```

Btw, when i use in controller in function callback-> `dd(Socialize::with("facebook"))` i got:

```
FacebookProvider {#443 ▼
  #graphUrl: "https://graph.facebook.com"
  #version: "v2.2"
  #scopes: array:1 [▶]
  #request: Request {#37 ▶}
  #clientId: "1009001095844880"
  #clientSecret: "My secret Id"
  #scopeSeparator: ","
  #encodingType: 1
  +"redirectUrl": "http://skarbonka.local:8081/callback"
}
```

The problem is  that Facebook  does not return parameters of user  to me

Comment: Is it socialize or socialite?

Comment: In config/app i made that: 'Socialize' => 'Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite'

Comment: Turn on error logging or check the log file in `/storage/logs/`

Comment: i got: local.ERROR: exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error response [url] https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me?access_token=EAAIWPp2bnoQBAHNVP4ZC4xs5bqcWpyqZAnkOro64zSym1TOS8TwRw2brXeIltb4GOkx9T7sqjpBHSWA2G2ZC6wXjdxZAKR3cbChyFJpR4Gvq21KuJ26fDewZCetRXMCrYZAz8R0ehBVxOZBX3HjPxhpPxjDAaNG7WLKXBNij9pjDwZDZD [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request' in /home/szymon/Projekty/skarbonka/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:71